# Converting String List to Single Quoted List in C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have list of strings. I want to convert each element of it to single quoted string (i.e "ABC" --> 'ABC'), How to do this in .net.

Thanks,
Omkar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have regular strings s to 's' (quoted string) and you wanted a List<> to be converted.

```
        List<string> stringList = new List<string>();
        //Fill the list with strings here.
        var query = from str in stringList
                    select string.Format("\'{0}\'", str);

        List<string> quotedList = query.ToList<string>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Linq can help here.

```
var newList = oldList.Select(c => c.Replace("\"", "'"));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is already well answered.  However, I have the hunch that you are taking a list of strings in C#, then trying to build an SQL expression for use in `IN` statements, e.g.:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name IN ('John','Mary','Peter')
```

In that case, you'd need to join the strings together, as well as protect from code injection attacks by doubling any single-quote characters.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (string entry in list) {
  if (sb.Length > 0) sb.Append(",");
  sb.Append("\'" + entry.Replace("'","''") + "\'");
}
string expr = sb.ToString();
```

You'd also need to handle the special case when the list is empty because `IN ()` is not a valid syntax for SQL.

**If this is not what you want, just ignore me.  :-)**

Comment: If your hunch is correct, how about avoid SQL injection hole and use parameters instead?

Comment: @Si, using parameters is really the proper way to go, if you are using one database backend. It might be better to dynamically construct SQL or use an ORM tool for the flexibility of moving to another database engine down the road.

Comment: @Stephen, @Si: How do you use parameters with the `IN` operator?

Comment: @Gabe, Hhmmmm... good question. Learn something new everyday.  Apparently you can't, not without some major trickery.  I found the following link: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=544951

Comment: @Stephen: Indeed, and then you might run into the limit on parameter count well before you run into the limit on items in an `IN` clause.

Comment: You just iterate item in the list: @param1, @param2, etc. and then set the param value accordingly. I use the field/column name as the param name for easier debugging/tracing. You end up with sql `WHERE field IN (@field1, @field2, ...)` and we have never hit limit on parameter count.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace all double with single quotes, simply do this:

```
myString = myString.Replace( "\"", "'" );
```

However, note that `'` is not a valid string delimiter in C#, so you can't have the string `'ABC'`, but you can have the string `"'ABC'"` that contains the text `'ABC'`

**EDIT**

When looking at Geoff's answer, I saw that you wanted a list. In that case, his answer is *almost* correct- Try this variant instead:

```
var convertedList = myStringList.Select(s => s = s.Replace("\"", "'").ToList();
```

Comment: I think you should call ToList afterwards.

Comment: @Stephen - Yes. that would probably be better :) Changed it now. Thanks.